# Properties of integers $x^n+2$ when $n \ge 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-factorization, perfect-powers

If $x$ is an integer, the numbers $x^2+2$ have some well-known properties (*e.g.,* because they are of the form $a^2+2b^2$, their prime factors are as well).

When $n \ge 3$, do the integers $x^n+2$ have any well-known properties? Have they been studied?

Comment: For $n=3$, see https://oeis.org/A084380